# #1062 - Дублирующаяся запись '235-74' по ключу 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне надо заменить в БД значение ячейки, если оно попадает под условие. Делаю такой запрос:

```
UPDATE
  oc_product_to_category
SET
  category_id = 74
WHERE
  category_id = 68
  OR category_id = 70
  OR category_id = 69
  OR category_id = 72
  OR category_id = 73
  OR category_id = 85
  OR category_id = 84
  OR category_id = 71
```

Получаю ошибку указанную в заголовке. Как исправить?

Comment: category_id - входит в выражение первичного ключа. Его (выражения) значение должно быть уникально в каждой записи (нет другой записи с таким значением). А Вы хотите сделать таких дублей аж 8 штук - ясен пень сервер сопротивляется...

Comment: category_id там не первичный ключ. Первичный ключ там product_id http://prntscr.com/mrtdub

Comment: Да ни фига! первичный ключ составной - (product_id, category_id). Т.е. уникальный должна быть пара полей. Т.е. УЖЕ имеется запись с product_id=235 и category_id=74, а ты хочешь изменить запись с product_id=235 и category_id=68 (или другим category_id из списка). Альтернативно - имеется минимум 2 записи с product_id=235 и category_id из списка. Это и приведёт к дублированию выражения первичного ключа (значений этой пары полей). PS. И вместо скриншотов вежливые люди показывают CREATE TABLE в текстовой форме.

Comment: @Akina Все - посмотрел таблицу - понял. А можно как-то переписать запрос, чтобы если например после замены ключ будет дублироваться то удалить строку?

Comment: @Lichtgestalt Сомневаюсь. Проверяйте и удаляйте все до, а потом делайте обновление.

Comment: *А можно как-то переписать запрос, чтобы если например после замены ключ будет дублироваться то удалить строку?* Нет. Дубликаты - это ДВЕ записи (и они, хоть и типа дубли, но всё же различаются, скажем, по внутреннему номеру). Из которых должна быть удалена одна ОПРЕДЕЛЁННАЯ. А вот какая именно - неизвестно.